# How can I initialize a record type in PL/SQL without null parameters

Tags: plsql, initialization, record

I have a record type like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CUSTOM_REC_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
     ID                                NUMBER(19),
     COLUMN1                           NUMBER(19),
     COLUMN2                           NUMBER(19),
     COLUMN3                           NUMBER(19),
     COLUMN4                           NUMBER(19),
     .....                                       ,
     .....                                       ,
     .....                                       ,
     .....                                       
)
```

I need to initialize a record of this type. Using the following syntax:

```
l_custom_rec                    :=    CUSTOM_REC_TYPE();
```

doesn't work. I get the message:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CUSTOM_REC_TYPE'
```

I guess I need to pass all values as parameters, namely:

```
l_custom_rec                    :=    CUSTOM_REC_TYPE(null, null, null, .....);
```

**Can I avoid this? Is there a way to use my record without such a long initialization?** (the record type has 90 components).
In case I don't initialize it at all, I get the error:

```
ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
```

**There are other cases where I declare the type in a package, where I don't need an initialization at all. How is this possible?**

Comment: You have mixed two different and incompatible concepts. `CUSTOM_REC_TYPE` is not a record but object data type. They are very different. Oracle gives you a default constructor where you have to pass a value for each object attribute but you can define your own constructors. StackOverflow is full of examples for all of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use record instead of object, you do not have to initialize it anyway. You can also use `tablename%rowtype` instead of defining the type explicitly.

```
declare
  TYPE CUSTOM_REC_TYPE IS RECORD
  (
   ID                                NUMBER(19),
   COLUMN1                           NUMBER(19),
   COLUMN2                           NUMBER(19),
   COLUMN3                           NUMBER(19),
   COLUMN4                           NUMBER(19),
   .....                                       
  );
  x custom_rec_type;
  y tablename%rowtype;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(x.id));
end;
```

Comment: Is this a 12c specific solution ? In 11g type compilation fails with `PLS-00103` as records are PL/SQL only data structures.

Comment: @user272735 answer corrected and rowtype hint added.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION:

```
create or replace type custom_rec_type as object
(
     id                                number(19),
     column1                           number(19),
     column2                           number(19),
     column3                           number(19),
     column4                           number(19),
     constructor function custom_rec_type
     ( id                                number default null,
       column1                           number default null,
       column2                           number default null,
       column3                           number default null,
       column4                           number default null
     ) return self as result
);

create or replace type body custom_rec_type as
     constructor function custom_rec_type
     ( id                                number default null,
       column1                           number default null,
       column2                           number default null,
       column3                           number default null,
       column4                           number default null
     ) return self as result
     is
     begin
        self.id := id;
        self.column1 := column1;
        self.column2 := column2;
        self.column3 := column3;
        self.column4 := column4;
        return;
     end;
end;
```

Now you can do this:

```
declare
   crt1 custom_rec_type;
   crt2 custom_rec_type;
begin
   crt1 := custom_rec_type();
   crt2 := custom_rec_type(column4=>23);
end;
```